# Bitrix self hosted - page not found

Tags: bitrix

i have install Bitrix self hosted licence on dedicated server. I go through manual and installation was fine.
After i access bitrix and go to crm or my profile receive error: Not Found
The requested URL /company/personal/user/1/ was not found on this server.

If we go on CRM menu then receive:
Not Found
The requested URL /crm/deal/kanban/ was not found on this server.

And i check and this folders doesn't exist.

Does anybody know why folders aren't created?

Answer (score 0):

Urls like `/crm/deal/kanban/` etc. are SEF urls. This folder shouldn't exist, it's OK.

Check if `.htaccess` file in web root exists and works properly.